# Entity Framework context not clearing between where clauses

Tags: wpf, datagrid, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6.0 with WPF. I initilaly load my data to a datagrid with one where clause condition. Then the user can change the where clause from the UI. What is happening is the first where clause on load works fine. Then when the second where clause is executed the data is added to the first local context. Is there a way to clear the local context so that when another query is performed the context does not contain the data from both?

I tried to detach the context but I'm getting an error: _context.Entry(abc).State = EntityState.Detached;

```
try
{
   _context.myData.Where(x => x.myFlag == true).Load();
}

catch (Exception except)
{
    // error
}

myVSource.Source = _context.myData.Local;

\\ then I have a click even which chnages the where clause

private void RefreshData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _context.myData.Where(x => x.myFlag == false).Load();
}
```

Comment: The usual way is to bind UI to self tracking viewmodels. Copy data from model to viewmodel - edit - copy data from viewmodel to model savechanges.  New up the context around each database call. Like you'd open and close an ado connection around any database call.

Comment: I'm using a viewmodel. The myVSource is used in a CollectionsViewSource and its bound in xaml. So I need a way to clear the local data between queries. Do you know how this can be achieved using the small snippet of code I attached.

Comment: Somehow raise propertychanged or collectionchanged. By changing something in the code you've not shown us.

Comment: @HALO: Instead of trying to clear the context, why don't you simply create a new one?

Comment: can you show me that in code above

Comment: also, I'm using this context in other parts of my code. Wouldn't creating a new one cause a lot of issues.

Comment: Well, not doing it also causes issues, as you see. If you only read the data you should use `AsNoTracking` and, hence, not `Load()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a solution. In the click event, I simply added:

_context.Set().Local.ToList().ForEach(x => _context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Detached);

before _context.myData.Where(x => x.myFlag == false).Load();
and it cleared the current data displayed.